# How to select more WYSIWYG editor with protractor?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests, angularjs-e2e

I have 2 WYSIWYG editor on the page, I select first and enter the source code, after that i want to select second WYSIWYG editor and enter source code, but protractor enter source code at first WYSIWYG editor?

My code for that:

```
    // First WYGWYSI editor
    element.all(by.css("div[role='application']")).get(0).element(by.cssContainingText("span","Tools")).click();
    element(by.cssContainingText('span','Source code')).click();
    element(by.css("div[role='application'] textarea")).sendKeys("HTML code");
    element(by.css("div[role='application']")).element(by.partialButtonText("Ok")).click();

    // Second WYGWYSI editor
    element.all(by.css("div[role='application']")).get(1).element(by.cssContainingText("span","Tools")).click();
    element(by.cssContainingText('span','Source code')).click();
    element(by.css("div[role='application'] textarea")).sendKeys("HTML1 code");
    element(by.css("div[role='application']")).element(by.partialButtonText("Ok")).click();
```

This is my WYSIWYG editor http://prntscr.com/feyton

Answer (score 0):

Adding inline comments to the above code to show what's actually happening here:

```
// First WYGWYSI editor
// -- Click on the application 0
element.all(by.css("div[role='application']")).get(0).element(by.cssContainingText("span","Tools")).click();

// -- Clicked on source code
element(by.cssContainingText('span','Source code')).click();

// -- Sends keys to the first editor and clicks "Ok". Since 
//    element(by.css("div[role='application']")) has multiple matching
//    elements, return the first one.
element(by.css("div[role='application'] textarea")).sendKeys("HTML code");
element(by.css("div[role='application']")).element(by.partialButtonText("Ok")).click();

// Second WYGWYSI editor
// -- Click onthe application. The second one!
element.all(by.css("div[role='application']")).get(1).element(by.cssContainingText("span","Tools")).click();

// -- Oh no! We click on the first <span> with text Source code.  This is 
//    is (guessing) the first editor.
element(by.cssContainingText('span','Source code')).click();
element(by.css("div[role='application'] textarea")).sendKeys("HTML1 code");
// -- Click on the first "Ok" button (we did not click the second button with Ok).
element(by.css("div[role='application']")).element(by.partialButtonText("Ok")).click();
```

What probably should happen is, we should first the editor we are interested in and pick the element in the context of the editor.

```
let firstEditor = element.all(by.css("div[role='application']")).get(0);
let secondEditor = element.all(by.css("div[role='application']")).get(1);

// First WYGWYSI editor
firstEditor.element(by.cssContainingText("span","Tools")).click();
firstEditor.element(by.cssContainingText('span','Source code')).click();
firstEditor.element(by.css("textarea")).sendKeys("HTML code");
firstEditor.element(by.partialButtonText("Ok")).click();

// Second WYGWYSI editor
secondEditor.element(by.cssContainingText("span","Tools")).click();
secondEditor.element(by.cssContainingText('span','Source code')).click();
secondEditor.element(by.css("textarea")).sendKeys("HTML1 code");
secondEditor.element(by.partialButtonText("Ok")).click();
```